# How to archive POP3 mailbox?

Tags: email

What programs are available to archive a mailbox (to mbox or maildir format) that I can only access via POP3? I'd like to be able to browse the mailbox locally afterwards, probably using mutt or the like.

I'm on Debian stable, no problem to compile from source if needed, commandline preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefere `fetchmail`. It can fetch from POP3 or IMAP accounts, to local directory.
You can then use mutt for browseing it.

Cheers,

Comment: Than you for the hint, this seems difficult to configure for a one-time backup of a POP mailbox though.

Comment: I read up on fetchmail further, it either needs a MDA or an MTA which I don't have installed and can not install. 

Are there tools without the need for either?

Comment: You can use `procmail` as a MDA. Also pretty easy to set-up.

Answer (score 3):

`fetchmail(1)` reduced config that I actually used for the purpose of pulling from POP3 and delivering to a Maildir:

```
set daemon 300

poll mail.domain.com proto POP3
    user "user@domain.com" pass "VerySecret"
    fetchall
    no keep
    no rewrite
    mda "procmail"
```

Combined with a `procmail(1)` config ~/.procmailrc:

```
MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir/
DEFAULT=$MAILDIR
```